# Triple jointure table in spring hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I am making a quiz application and I'm not sure how to go about the database relation for this example.

I have a Question objects which should contain a list of possible Answers. The Answer object is not unique to a question, so there's already a many-to-many relation here.

Now, I have a Quiz object, which should contain a list of Question to display and remember which Answers were selected. As some answers are common to multiple questions, I want to remember precisely for which Question the Answer was selected.

The only solution I see for that is to also have a SelectedAnswer table, which would refer to Quiz, Question and Answer to remember for which Question in which Quiz the answer was selected. It should be enough to generate the score and result of the quiz, and also pause the quiz in the middle while still remembering the selected answers.

Would this solution work/be the best? If so, what should my Java objects look like ?

At the moment I have this (I'm still figuring out the join column annotation):

Question:

```
@ManyToMany List<Answer> possibleAnswers
```

Answer:

```
@ManyToMany List<Question> questions
```

Quiz:

```
@ManyToMany List<Question> questions
@ManyToMany List<SelectedAnswer> selectedAnswers
```

SelectedAnswer:

```
Quiz quiz;
Question question;
Answer answer;
```

Comment: Just take a paper and a pen and draw the entities and their relationships. Make sure that you name the relationships. That will bring you easy to the answer

Comment: That's what I did and how I came up with the triple jointure table. Is there something I'm missing @SimonMartinelli ?

Comment: Maybe you would need something like a QuestionAnswer relationship. In you Quiz you have to lists and they are not related

Comment: QuestionAnswer will exist for the many to many relationship between question and answer. But I still need additional information to remember specifically for which question an answer was picked, otherwise I could run into the issue of having an answer selected for one question and not for the other, that is recognized as good for both.